# How can I center my div to the center of the page while applying a margin?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this without hacks.

My goal is to center my .paper element to the center of the page, while leaving space between that and the header.

https://jsfiddle.net/8L4ud0e8/

As you can see, I centered the .paper element by adding:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

However, it is "touching" the header now. Normally, I'd add `margin: 20px;` to put some space between them but this is now not an option because of the way it is centered. How can I move the .paper element down to not touch the header? (I don't want a margin-top hack because it just band-aids the main issue)

Comment: `margin-top:` no? How does that make anything worse?

Comment: It makes the .paper element touch all the way the bottom of the page (where as there should be space)

Comment: No it doesnt: https://jsfiddle.net/8L4ud0e8/2/

Comment: Do you want vertical, horizontal, or both centering?

Comment: @ifconfig that is because the width in this example isn't auto, and there no content.

Comment: Try it. It doesn't

Comment: It's difficult to accurately reproduce the issue and suggest a working solution if the example provided doesn't accurately represent the real-world issue. If content matters you should add some to your fiddle so that we can see the effects you are referring to when declaring a `margin-top` value. Otherwise, if it's just a little space you need to separate `.paper` from any element above or below it, you can use `margin: 20px auto;`

Comment: This is an example with text in the `paper` div. Still centered horiz. and vertically: https://jsfiddle.net/8L4ud0e8/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a flex wrapper and a height calculation.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 2em); /*Subtract .header's height*/
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="paper"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mooqc3p3/

Comment: I like this solution better than the one I proposed :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the height of both elements, you can use `calc()` to create the top margin.

```
margin-top = 50vh - 50px - 25px    // half the heights of the viewport, the header, and the .paper
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8L4ud0e8/4/

However, this obviously only works if you have fixed size elements and your container is the same height as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution might be:

```
header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Just add the white space to the .header element, not the paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it vertically centered in the remaining space:

```
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 100px);
```